# How do I center an image without being offset when scaling browser/ using mobile device?

Tags: html, css, image, device, scaling

So I've been trying to make the logo on my website centered and stay in the center when looking at it on a phone or changing browser size, but no matter what I do it will be more and more offset from the center the smaller the browser

Here's my code:

```
    img#logo{
    top:20px; 
    width:570px; 
    height:125px;
    position: absolute;
    left:39%;
    }
```

Comment: Does the image have to have `position:absolute;`?

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are looking for horizontally center or vertically or both ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
img#logo{
top:20px; 
width:570px; 
height:125px;
position: absolute;
left:0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<img id="logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ84hMKGYnLjbYASltpjWRIIumEGrwWPmkDFVkkr4hppCPekUIY">
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the image by a block element and use text-align: center.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

img#logo {
  width: 570px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img#logo{
    top:20px; 
    width:570px; 
    height:125px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -260px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center the image using position:absoulte and transform property.
The image will re-adjust with all screens and all resolutions

```html
<style>

img#logo {
position: absolute;
width:570px; 
height:125px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
<img id="logo" src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/images/bg.jpg">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Horizontally center**

Use below css

```
img#logo {
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 570px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```css
img#logo {
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 570px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300">
```

**Horizontally and vertically center**

Use below css

```
img#logo {
  width: 570px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
img#logo {
  width: 570px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300">
```

**Vertically center**

Use below css

```
img#logo {
  width: 570px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform:translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```css
img#logo {
  width: 570px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform:translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300">
```